# What's the options to host a Thrift service?

Tags: c#, thrift

I am just started exploring Thrift framework. I'd like to build a Thrift service in C# that will be hosted on a windows server. Right now, according varies tutorials, I am able create a Thrift service within a console application project.

However, I am wondering how the actual Thrift service is going to be hosted under Windows server. Should I build a window service application that launch the Thrift service?

Answer (score 3):

There are three options:

1. Console Application
2. Windows Service
3. Http Service using IIS. [Here's a post](http://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/thrift-over-http-with-iis/) on how to set it up on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the choice is in your hands. You can incorporate the thrift service in a console app or a windows service application based on your requirements.